# How to draw multivalued attribute in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

[image: This is the ER Diagram in workbench]I am following a book on Fundamentals of Database Systems by Elmasri & Navathe. In the book there is an Entity called DEPARTMENT and it has a multivalued attribute called location. I could not figure out a way to represent location in my ER Diagram which should have an identifying relation with the department entity. Should I draw an Entity named LOCATION and create a relationship with the DEPARTMENT entity or is there another way to represent multivalued attribute in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EER implementation in MySQL Workbench is not a full implementation the relationship model. It rather focuses on things that can be represented in a MySQL database. That means things like inheritance or multi-valued attributes cannot be modelled there. And I'm also not aware of a way to simulate that, unless you use another entity that has all the attributes which the original attribute needed.

In your case it makes sense to have a `location` entity that has a relationship with the `department` entity. Not sure if that should be an identifying relationship, since a location is not mandatory, is it? E.g. it could be a department is stored that no longer exists and hence has no location.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Lischke. I added a new location entity diagram and created the relationship with the department entity, It works fine. However, when I reverse engineer the schema, MySQL workbench does draw the diagram for multivalued attribute.

Comment: Hmm, maybe we are not talking about the same thing then :-) Can you post a screenshot somewhere with some markup showing that attribute?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the snapshot of the ER-diagram. In the diagram I added the department location entity manually and created the relationship with the department entity.